# Xamarin.IOS How do you present a fixed Time using DateTime?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How do you get the time in a fixed period to show? for example, 
1:00pm - 2:00 pm
I am able to get the day of the week, month and year to show but how do you get the time?

private DateTime[] customDates;

```
          {

        customDates = new DateTime[]
        {

            DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*2),
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*3), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*4)
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

You would generally either use two DateTime objects to represent the Start and End date, or a DateTime object to represent the Start and a TimeSpan object to represent the Duration.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
DateTime end = start.AddHours(2);
```

or

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(2,0,0);
```

[image]

Comment: When i use DateTime.Now it gives me the day of the week, month and day. Not the actual time. I just want to display the time. When i tried using DateTime objects it still displayed the date and not the time

Comment: DateTime is an object that represents a date and time - how it displays that value when output is highly configurable.  It's unclear exactly what you're doing to output the value since you didn't provide any code.

Comment: i edited my post that has the code im using to get the date but i want to be able to get a time frame

Comment: I still don't see why you think there is no time value.  If you examine those objects in the debugger they should have properties for Hours, Minutes and Seconds reflecting the time they were created.

Comment: see my edit for a screenshot of the debugger displaying the Time and Date properties of DateTime.Now

Comment: okay thanks! i got it but i have another question, how do you check the date? like if today's date is sunday, skip it and show monday

Comment: if you look at the image, it shows that DateTime has a DayOfWeek property